# I have an AWS access key and I have created an SQS queue but still can't access SQS using python boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

So, I have an `AWS Access Key Id` and its respective `AWS Secret Key`. Furthermore from the AWS dashboard I have created a queue in SQS and put a test message in the queue. I have downloaded `boto` for Python. However, when I try to run even the most basic command, I get an error:

```
import boto.sqs
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region('us-west-2',
                                  aws_access_key_id = settings.AWSAccessKeyId,
                                  aws_secret_access_key = settings.AWSSecretKey)
print conn.get_all_queues()
exit()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_prog.py", line 43, in <module>
    print conn.get_all_queues()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/sqs/connection.py", line 446, in get_all_queues
    return self.get_list('ListQueues', params, [('QueueUrl', Queue)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.SQSError: SQSError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>OptInRequired</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id needs a subscription for the service.</Message>
    <Detail/>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>45255e1e-aaff-548b-9d71-105bda134530</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

The keys are correct, I am using them successfully in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with this for hours, and right after I post the question here I find the answer.

The trick is that apparently you can't use AWS root keys for this, you have to create an IAM user and give SQS permissions to that user.

Comment: What SQS permissions did you provide here?